# Broadcast Receiver.onReceive: When new message's available for reading (using Cursor)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

When I set Broadcast Receiver to the new SMS message event it takes control and I am able to get all details of the new SMS message that just came in. That's not what I want.

I want to use that event like a poke for another method, which will read all the SMS from

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse ("content://sms/inbox");
```

Using Cursor. Let me call it SMS bulk reading.

But what I've noticed is that the hot SMS isn't available yet to be read at the time when onReceive is fired.

Question: When will the news SMS be available : right after onReceived is served?

Or maybe there is a time delay for a new message to be available for my bulk reading procedure ?

Comment: why cant u add (current message + other locally saved messaged) like this u'll get all bulk messages

Comment: because when reading bulk, I get ItemsArray[19] with all SMS details.. but inside onReceive each time call a particular method to get specific detail of SMS..

Comment: didn't get still

Answer (score 0):

## Let me publish my version of the answer

Yes, it is available for bulk reading after onReceived event is served.

I use the Handler with delay from UI class:

```
Handler handler = new Handler ();
public void ReadDelayed() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            SMSBulkReader();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

and call it at the end of OnReceived event of BroadcastReceiver.